# Задача с переносом текста, и работой с файлами на С

Tags: c

Задан текст, состоящий из предложений – групп слов, заканчивающихся точкой и пробе-
лом. Необходимо вывести на экран каждое предложение с новой строки. 
*Входные* данные должны вводиться из
файла, а  выходные выводиться в файл. 
Файл предполагает большой объем данных, а не одну строку !

---

С первой частью разобрался. Ввожу с клавиатуры, выводит как надо.
Не могу сделать считывание и запись в файл всего этого.

Comment: Может опишете конкретную проблему? Покажете что уже сделали?

Comment: Вот, что есть сейчас http://pastebin.com/PGYUTr63

Answer (score 3):

./a.out < input-file > output-file

А если серьезно, то передаете имена в параметрах командной строки. Открываете

```
FILE *in = fopen(av[1],"r"), *out = fopen(av[2],"w");
```

один на чтение, другой на запись. Естественно проверки не забывайте.

Далее как делали, только вместо stdin читаете in, и пишете в out, а не в stdout.

Comment: Если написано уже много кода, а сама задача некритичная (учебная, маленькая), можно еще посоветовать `freopen(av[1], "r", stdin);` и `freopen(av[2], "2", stdout);`

Comment: Это совершенно правильно, просто решил курсанту голову не забивать.